# Batch Help - Remove String Between Parentheses in Folder Name

Tags: for-loop, batch-file, cmd

Trying to produce a batch file to look at a directory (G:Videos) and rename the sub folders by removing anything between parentheses (and including the parentheses themselves).

Example:

G:Videos

- \Folder (Text 1)
- \Another Folder (LettersOnly)
- \2013 (Words 2)
- \Example2

The ideal solution would produce:

G:Videos

- \Folder
- \Another Folder
- \2013
- \Example2

I'd like to schedule this to run at a certain time every day because new folders will get added to the directory with parentheses daily.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Will there ever be anything to be kept AFTER the `(whatever)`? Or can `' ('` be taken as the start point from where to delete all onwards?

Comment: No, any text that is needed will come before (whatever). Everything else can be discarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
pushd "g:\videos"
for /d %%i in (*.*) do for /f "delims=(" %%j in ("%%~i") do if "%%~i" neq "%%~j" echo ren "%%~i" "%%~nj"
popd
```

Remove the `echo` if the output is OK.